# Create DNN user from console / windows application

Tags: dotnetnuke

My requirement might be very basic, but i'm new to DNN technology. google search doesn't help me.

I have millions of users in sql server with all details like password firstname, lastname, ....

I just want to move these users to DNN database. What is the best way for that ? It can be any stored procedure calling or I can write console application for that.

I created console application, but it is saying nullreference error, as it is a console application and unable to read site configuration, is there a way to manually set the configurations?

I am using latest version of DNN software and .NET 4.0. c#

Answer (score 0):

aspx page option:

Create a new page in root of dnn that inherints from `dotnetnuke.framework.pagebase` and use this [dnn wiki page](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/page/Create-a-New-User-and-Add-to-Specific-Role-Programatically) to see how you can easily create user and add it to specific role.

Windows/console application option:

You can look at http://iweb.adefwebserver.com/ which is a windows application and consuming dnn api with some web services to get data from dnn. That will be a good starting point.